# reading from a file descriptor in C

Tags: c, file-descriptor

(correct me if im wrong on my terms) So i need to read from a file descriptor, but the read method takes in a int for byte size to read that much OR i can use O_NONBLOCK, but i still have to setup up a buffer size of an unknown size. making it difficult. heres what i have so far

this is my method that handles all the polling and mkfifo. and N is already predefined in main

```
struct pollfd pfd[N];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    char fileName[32];
    snprintf (fileName, sizeof(fileName), "%d_%di", pid, i);
    mkfifo(fileName, 0666);
    pfd[i].fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY | O_NDELAY);
    pfd[i].events = POLLIN;
    pfd[i].revents = 0;

    snprintf (fileName, sizeof(fileName), "%d_%do", pid, i);
    mkfifo(fileName, 0666);
    i++;
    pfd[i].fd = open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_NDELAY);
    pfd[i].events = POLLOUT;
    pfd[i].revents = 0;
    i--;
}
while(1)
{
    int len, n;
    n = poll(pfd, N, 2000);
    if( n < 0 )
    {   
        printf("ERROR on poll");
        continue;
    }
    if(n == 0)
    {
        printf("waiting....\n");
        continue;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        char buff[1024]; <---i dont want to do this

        if (pfd[i].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            printf("Processing input....\n");
            read(pfd[i].fd, buff, O_NONBLOCK);
            readBattlefield(buff);
            print_battleField_stats();
            pfd[i].fd = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

i also read somewhere that once read() reads all the data coming, it empties the pipe, meaning i can use the same again for another incoming data. but it doesnt empty the pipe because i cant use the same pipe again. I asked my professor but all he says was to use something like scanf, but how do use scanf if scanf takes a FILE stream, and the poll.fd is an int? essentially my ultimate question is, how to read the incoming data through the file descriptor using scan or of other sort? using scan will help me more with handling the data.

EDIT:
in another terminal i have to put cat file > (named_file)
and my main program will read the input data. heres what the input data looks like

3 3

1 2 0

0 2 0

3 0 0

first 2 numbers are grid information and player number, and after that is grid, but this a simplified version, ill be dealing with sizes over 100's of players and grids of over 1000's

Comment: Make your buffer the size of the chunk of data you are prepared to handle at any given time, then handle that much repeatedly.  Or if you fdopen() the fd you can get a FILE * and use fscanf() on that.

Comment: Side note - your pfd initialisaion tricks with `i++` and `i--` don't looks right.

Comment: Can you post an example of what your input data looks like?

Comment: @keltar you're right, I thought it worked, but thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are a saint lol, its these methods that i never know that always save, no matter the amount of research i do, i can never stumble upon the correct methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> char buff[1024]; <---i dont want to do this

What would you like to do then?  This is how it works.  This is **not** how it works:

```
read(pfd[i].fd, buff, O_NONBLOCK);
```

This will compile because `O_NONBLOCK` is an integer `#define`, but it is *absolutely and unequivocally* incorrect.  The third argument to `read()` is a number of bytes to read.  Not a flag. Period.  It may be zero, but what you've done here is pass an arbitrary number -- whatever the value of `O_NONBLOCK` is, which could easily be more than 1024, the size of your buffer.  This **does not set the read non-block**.  `recv()` is similar to `read()` and does take such flags as a forth argument, but you can't use that with a *file* descriptor.  If you want to set non-block on a file descriptor, you must do it with `open()` or `fcntl()`.

> how to read the incoming data through the file descriptor using scan or of other sort?

You can create a `FILE*` stream from an open descriptor with `fdopen()`.

> i also read somewhere that once read() reads all the data coming, it empties the pipe, meaning i can use the same again for another incoming data. but it doesnt empty the pipe because i cant use the same pipe again.

Once you reach EOF (because the writer closed the connection), `read()` will return 0, and continue to return 0 immediately until someone opens the pipe again.

If you set the descriptor non-block, `read()` will always return immediately; if there is someone connected and nothing to read, it will return -1 but `errno` will `== EAGAIN`.  See `man 2 read`.

`man fifo` is definitely something you should read; if there's anything you aren't sure about, ask a specific question based on that.

And don't forget: **Fix that `read()` call.**  It's wrong.  W R O N G.  Your prof/TA/whoever will not miss that.

Comment: This; i also read somewhere that once read() reads all the data coming, it empties the pipe, meaning i can use the same again for another incoming data. but it doesn’t empty the pipe because i cant use the same pipe again.   Is definitely not true.  the pipe does not close for the receiver unless the sender closes their end of the pipe or the receiver deliberately closes it.

Comment: Actually I just tried this and I was wrong about the read fd being defunct after EOF; I've corrected that above.  `read()` will return 0 **immediately** once EOF is reached (because the writer closed the pipe) BUT if another writer `open()`s the pipe for writing, this will stop, and you can continue to read from the new writer.